# Versioning commercial datasets in ArcSDE + Oracle

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, versioning

We are building an application with several spatial tables, provided by a commercial vendor, at its core. The vendor provides updates quarterly. We maintain several tables of our own, derived from these commercial tables. Our application would benefit from versioning the commercial tables along with our derived tables, such that we can see a consistent view of things at any point in time.

Upon each update from the vendor, I would like to "diff" the changes and apply them to our database, then update our derived tables accordingly. Can this be accomplished with ESRI's implementation of versioning? Would this require registering our tables with the GDB? (I prefer to do the heavy lifting with PL/SQL, so I'm not sure how I feel about this.)

Comment: Is the vendor able to send you disconnected replicas?  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Replicas_in_a_disconnected_environment/00270000002z000000/

Comment: Vendor data comes in shapefile (SHP) format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question corrrectly IMO the answer is no. Versioning simply stated tracks changes to existing data within the database.

I used to use a modelbuilder script to check incoming shape files for "diff" in both the spatial and attributes, make a selection of the new differing data and then export that to a seperate file for import to my db.

There is a [script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14742) available to check two sde layers.

For more on versioning (in case you are interested)
[system tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002m0000007r000000.htm)
[Quick view of versioning](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00270000000r000000.htm)
[Long and short transaction support](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000007000000.htm)
[Data maintenance transactions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002700000001000000.htm)